# How to take a picture and set it as my ImageButton, without using the deprecated method startActivityForResult()?

Tags: java, android

This is my current code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            ibPic.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"));
        }
    }
```

I tried using `ActivityResultLauncher`  and `registerForActivityResult()` but it didn't work out.

Comment: Post the code you tried as that is the way.

Comment: Use [`ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview?hl=en) if you want a `Bitmap` back. Please bear in mind that camera apps are buggy and may not be reliable for requests like this. Only use `TakePicturePreview` or `TakePicture` if you are fine with the camera apps failing to work as expected. Use CameraX or another camera library and take the picture directly in your app if you need greater control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can use **ActivityResultLauncher** to achieve this. Below are the steps:

**1. Registration**

- Use registerForActivityResult with a chosen contract and result callback.

**2. Launching**

- Replace startActivityForResult with launch on your
  ActivityResultLauncher.

**3. Handling Results**

- Extract result information from the ActivityResult object in the
  callback.

> Example

public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ImageButton imageButton;
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraLauncher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    imageButton = findViewById(R.id.your_image_button_id);

    // Set up the camera launcher for handling the result
    cameraLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                handleCameraResult(result);
            }
        }
    );

    // Set a click listener to open the camera when the image button is clicked
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openCamera();
        }
    });
}

// Function to open the camera
private void openCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        cameraLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent);
    }
}

// Function to handle the camera result. Handling Results**strong text**
private void handleCameraResult(ActivityResult result) {
    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent data = result.getData();
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageButton.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

}